# Trouble extracting regular expression out of a variable in JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm having issues with JMeter when trying to extract regular expression from a JMeter Variable.

[image: Test plan]

I'm generating a http request and getting the following response:

> {"Error":"OK","ErrorCode":0,"Data":[{"AppIconUrl":"http://a2.jqzfgh75x175-75.jpg","AppName":"26082014","AppProviderName":"f","BannerText":null,"BlockedSubAffiliates":["Unavailable"],"Categories":["games","kids"],"Creatives":[{"CreativeLink":"http://773gffff64ec6cffe3114cf789f9ca381c27e8a0_320x50.jpg","CreativeSize":"320x50","CreativeType":"Banner","Id":1234,"Name":"320x50.jpg"},{"CreativeLink":"http://77312bc1cfc3c281234_320x480.jpg","CreativeSize":"320x480","CreativeType":"FullScreen","Id":231,"Name":"320x480.jpg"},{"CreativeLink":"http://77312bc1cfc123452c7f_480x320.jpg","CreativeSize":"480x320","CreativeType":"FullScreen","Id":543,"Name":"480x320.jpg"},{"CreativeLink":"http://77312bc1cdgh7w33bc09e_320x480.jpg","CreativeSize":"320x480","CreativeType":"CompanionBanner","Id":9872,"Name":"Unavailable"},{"CreativeLink":"http://77312bc1cfcdgdhe555id!_320x480.mp4","CreativeSize":"320x480","CreativeType":"Video","Id":53433,"Name":"kid!_320x480.mp4"}],"DailyBudget":"Unavailable","Description":"Test
> app","DeviceIds":[],"IsDeviceIdMandatory":false,"MarketAppId":"com.teamlava.candy(test)","MinOsVersion":"2.3","Name":"test
> y","Networks":["WIFI","3G"],"OfferId":"75824","Payout":0.00001,"PayoutType":"CPM","Platforms":["Android"],"PreviewLink":"https://plndy.com","SupportedCountries":["AU","BR","CN","DE","IN","IL","CH","GB","US"],"TrackingLink":"http://clk.test.com/aff_c?tt_ls=b&offer_id=75824&aff_id=12&tt_appid=12(test)&tt_bannerid="},{"AppIconUrl":"http://a2.154qzpnbsu.175x175-75.jpg","AppName":"test26082014","AppProviderName":"y","BannerText":null,"BlockedSubAffiliates":["Unavailable"],"Categories":["games","kids"],"Creatives":[{"CreativeLink":"http://7731dfgmkl3428cf_320x50.jpg","CreativeSize":"320x50","CreativeType":"Banner","Id":98865554,"Name":"320x50.jpg"},{"CreativeLink":"http://77sdfgklsg0f_320x480.jpg","CreativeSize":"320x480","CreativeType":"FullScreen","Id":536372,"Name":"320x480.jpg"},{"CreativeLink":"http://7dfgh556a6c_480x320.jpg","CreativeSize":"480x320","CreativeType":"FullScreen","Id":985442525,"Name":"480x320.jpg"},{"CreativeLink":"http://7731grdk4_320x480.jpg","CreativeSize":"320x480","CreativeType":"CompanionBanner","Id":712,"Name":"Unavailable"},{"CreativeLink":"http://773tktkoid!_320x480.mp4","CreativeSize":"320x480","CreativeType":"Video","Id":63722,"Name":"bid!_320x480.mp4"}],"DailyBudget":"Unavailable","Description":"Test
> app2","DeviceIds":[],"IsDeviceIdMandatory":false,"MarketAppId":"aby(test)","MinOsVersion":"2.3","Name":"Test2
> 02122014","Networks":["WIFI","3G"],"OfferId":"3666","Payout":1.00000,"PayoutType":"CPC","Platforms":["Android"],"PreviewLink":"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamlava.candy","SupportedCountries":["AU","BR","CA","DE","IL","GB","US"],"TrackingLink":"http://clk.taptica.com/aff_c?tt_ls=b&offer_id=3666&aff_id=12&tt_appid=12(test)&tt_bannerid="}]}

When I'm trying to extract the following regular expressions out of the responses' body, it works fine:

> Regular expression 1: "ErrorCode":([0-9]+),|([0-9]+)</errorCode>
>
> Result 1: 0

[image: regular expression 1]

> Regular expression 2: {"AppIconUrl":(.+?)tt_bannerid="}|\n(.+?)\n|\n(.+?)$|(.+?)</Offer>
>
> Result 2: "http://a2.jqzfgh75x175-75.jpg","AppName":"26082014","AppProviderName":"f","BannerText":null,"BlockedSubAffiliates":["Unavailable"],"Categories":["games","kids"],"Creatives":[{"CreativeLink":"http://773gffff64ec6cffe3114cf789f9ca381c27e8a0_320x50.jpg","CreativeSize":"320x50","CreativeType":"Banner","Id":1234,"Name":"320x50.jpg"},{"CreativeLink":"http://77312bc1cfc3c281234_320x480.jpg","CreativeSize":"320x480","CreativeType":"FullScreen","Id":231,"Name":"320x480.jpg"},{"CreativeLink":"http://77312bc1cfc123452c7f_480x320.jpg","CreativeSize":"480x320","CreativeType":"FullScreen","Id":543,"Name":"480x320.jpg"},{"CreativeLink":"http://77312bc1cdgh7w33bc09e_320x480.jpg","CreativeSize":"320x480","CreativeType":"CompanionBanner","Id":9872,"Name":"Unavailable"},{"CreativeLink":"http://77312bc1cfcdgdhe555id!_320x480.mp4","CreativeSize":"320x480","CreativeType":"Video","Id":53433,"Name":"kid!_320x480.mp4"}],"DailyBudget":"Unavailable","Description":"Test app","DeviceIds":[],"IsDeviceIdMandatory":false,"MarketAppId":"com.teamlava.candy(test)","MinOsVersion":"2.3","Name":"test y","Networks":["WIFI","3G"],"OfferId":"75824","Payout":0.00001,"PayoutType":"CPM","Platforms":["Android"],"PreviewLink":"https://plndy.com","SupportedCountries":["AU","BR","CN","DE","IN","IL","CH","GB","US"],"TrackingLink":"http://clk.test.com/aff_c?tt_ls=b&offer_id=75824&aff_id=12&tt_appid=12(test)&

[image: regular expression 2]

Now, I'm trying to extract the following regular expressions out of result 2, but for some reason it doesn't work, and I only get the default value:

> Regular expression 3: (clk.+)&
>
> Expected Result 3: clk.test.com/aff_c?tt_ls=b&offer_id=75824&aff_id=12&tt_appid=12(test)
>
> Result 3 (default): empty_click_uri

[image: regular expression 3]

> Regular expression 4: "Id":([0-9]+)|[id:(.+?) |([0-9]+?)</Id>
>
> Expected Result 4: 1234
>
> Result 4 (default): empty_creative_id

[image]

I tested my regular expressions in https://regex101.com/ and the all seems to work fine. I can't figure out why it won't work over JMeter.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I couldnt find regex 4 from output of regex2. where is "</Id>" in output of regex 2 or in response1. I couldn't see it and same is happening with regex. Is it present in response body where you are searching all regex extrators? Paste what text you want to search with full response body. Probably we can help you then.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I was wrong, the regex #4 is: "Id":([0-9]+)|\[id:(.+?) |<Creative><Id>([0-9]+?)<\/Id>
I edited the request.
There are several options because sometimes I get the response in XML, sometimes in JSON and sometimes csv...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the reason it didn't work.

Because JMeter "knows" that these are variables and not expecting a string, there is no need for "$", "{" and "}".

The correct setup is:

[image: correct regular expression 3]

[image: correct regular expression 4]